# Rebuilding part of Android (libc)

Tags: android, libc, bionic

I've downloaded sources from http://source.android.com, and build them as in instruction.

But now I want to rebuild only `Bionic` `libc`.
Is it possible, without full build process?

Answer (score 0):

yes. if you ran build/envsetup.sh as the instructions for setting up the environment tell you you can  run 
`cd bionic` followed by `mm`
or 
`mmm bionic` from the root of your android tree
of 
`make bionic` (less sure about this one)
 and that should just remake the module. If you google for android build system you should find resources on the different build targets that you can run.